# How to compare length of three array? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to return false or alert or console.log('no true') if three list  there is not the same number of items?

```
example
arrOne = [1,2,3];
arrTwo = [5,6,7];
arrTthree = [1,9];
```

FALSE arrThree has 2 values , one and two have 3 values.
If same return true.

Comment: `arrOne.length === arrTwo.length && arrTwo.length === arrTthree.length`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @geofh They just want to compare the lengths, not the contents.

Comment: I need onlty lengths only

Answer (score 1):

I have similar idea like @geofh, but it need not wrap all your arrays into another one as input.

```js
function compare(...arrays) {
  return arrays.every(arr => arr.length === arrays[0].length);
}
```

With it, you could invoke `compare([1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [1, 9], ...)`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I owe you an answer since I erroneously marked it as duplicate. To generalize, you need a `sameLength` function that takes an array of arrays, perhaps. That could look like:

```
function sameLength(arrays) {
    return arrays.slice(1).every(arr => arr.length === arrays[0].length)
}
```

so `sameLength([arr1, arr2, arr3])` would return false in your case.